# Monk: how to get the last N records?

Tags: mongodb, monk

I can't find where this is documented. By default, the find() operation will get the records from beginning.

```
router.get('/chat/get-messages', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('chatMessages');
    collection.find({},{'limit':8},function(e,docs){
        if (e) return next(e);
        res.send(docs)
    });
});
```

How can I get the N last inserted records ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by `date` descending to get the last N records, and then call [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) on the `docs` array to put them back in ascending order:

```js
collection.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 8}, function(e, docs){
    if (e) return next(e);
    res.send(docs.reverse());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a workaround for what I wanted to do.

```
collection.find({},{sort: {"date": 1}},function(e,docs){
    if (e) return next(e);
    res.send(docs)
});
```

This returns the results ordered by date, I then sliced them on the client side :

```
$.getJSON( '/chat/get-messages', function( data ) {
    data=data.slice(data.length -8, data.length);
    ...
});
```

I am still waiting for a proper way to achieve this though.